# What is the difference between 決意 and 決心？

Tags: words, definitions

I have pondered this for a while but it seems that 決意 and 決心 can be used interchangeably as “determination” or “make up your mind” . I have checked on some [Japanese articles](https://okurukotoba.tokyo/archives/2424) as well, and there is some nuance to it, but does anybody have seen this on a real conversation, article or book?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate:  [What's the difference between 心, 念, and 意?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11901/78)